# sizeof(NULL) == 8?

Tags: c, sizeof

На `enSO` писали что `NULL` это `(void *)0`.

***Только вот мне не понятно каким образом константа `NULL` представлена указателем на `void` тип?***

**Ну и код:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(void) 
{
    printf("%d\n",sizeof(NULL)); /// 8
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 8 байт - это 64 бит? Система 64 битная? Тогда что не так?

Comment: @Sergey вопрос не об этом =)

Comment: Если действительно C, а не C++, то действительно так: #define NULL ((void *)0)
Размер указателя зависит не столько от разрядности системы, сколько от представления указателей. Указатель может содержать только смещение в сегменте или иметь структуру сегмент(селектор):смещение.

Comment: @paulgri вы хотите сказать что размер указателя не зависит от рязрядности системы? А последнее предложение я вообще никак не понимаю. Что значит содержит только смещение? Насколько мне известно указатель содержит адрес. Если вы говорите про что-то более продвинутое то либо до конца рассказывайте либо давайте ссылки на материалы где можно с этим ознакомиться

Comment: @MaximPro, в общем случае - да. Указатель может быть ближним (near) или дальним (far), это зависит от конкретной целевой платформы, способов адресации в ней, модели памяти при компиляции и т.п. Похожий вопрос уже был, посмотрите ответы http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/574302/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c-%d0%b2-c

Comment: @paulgri так вопрос то не про размер указателя если что =)

Comment: @MaximPro сформулируетй вопрос более корректно . `printf("%d\n",sizeof(NULL));` эквивалентно `printf("%d\n",sizeof((void*)0));`  И если на вашей системе возврашает `8` то Вы работаете в системе где адрес может хранится в  64-бит .

Comment: @paulgri, разве near и far всё ещё живы?

Comment: А на  какой еще? Поставьте себя на место разработчика и задайтесь этим вопросом. Все станет очевидно, лучше `void *` (к нему все типы указателей в Си автоматически приводятся) ничего не подходит.

Answer (score 6):

Оператор `sizeof` имеет тип возвращаемого значения `size_t`. Поэтому правильным будет указать спецификатор формата `zu`

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof(NULL)); 
        ^^^^^
```

Иначе функция `printf` в общем случае имеет неопределенное поведение.

Что касается вашего вопроса, то согласно стандарту языка C (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 3 **An integer constant expression with the value 0**, or such an
>   expression **cast to type void *, is called a null pointer
>   constant**.66) If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer
>   type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to
>   compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.

и (7.19 Common deﬁnitions )

> 3 The macros are
>
> ```
> NULL
> ```
>
> which expands to an implementation-deﬁned **null pointer constant**;

То есть ответ на ваш вопрос вытекает из определения константы `null pointer constant` и определения макроса `NULL`.

На используемой вами системе указатели, включая и `null pointer constants`, которая обычно определяется в C как

```
( void * )0
```

имеют размер, равный 8 байтам.

Comment: Получается, `sizeof NULL` implementation defined и может быть либо размером указателя, либо размером int'а?

Comment: @Qwertiy NULL в С определен как указатель. Представьте себе выражение char c = 'A'; int x = ( int )c; Следует ли из этого, что sizeof( ( int )c ) равно 1?

Comment: Ты же сам нацитировал: **An integer constant expression with the value 0**, or such an expression cast to type void *, **is called a null pointer constant** ... **NULL** which **expands to an implementation-deﬁned null pointer constant** - т. е. не запрещено вместо `#define NULL (void*)0` сделать просто `#define NULL 0`, как это сделано в плюсах. Получается, что `sizeof NULL` равен либо `sizeof (void*)`, либо `sizeof (int)` (в варианте `sizeof 0`). В чём именно ошибка таких рассуждений? Или есть ещё существенный кусок стандарта, который ты не включил в ответ?

Comment: @Qwertiy Ключевое значение в приведенной цитате имеют слова "cast to type void *". В C++  null pointer constant определяется как просто целочисленное значение. Но тем не менее там определяется понятие null pointer value, которое соответствует определению null pointer constant в C. То есть тоже используется приведение к указателю целочисленной константы. То есть в C там объединили и целочисленную константу и приведение к типу указателя в одно понятие. А в C++ это детализировали и разбили на два понятия.

Comment: "**or** such an expression cast to type void *" - тут ИЛИ - т. е. или 0, или он же, но приведённый к `void*`.

Comment: @Qwertiy Здесь или имеет отношение не к приведению типов, а к виду выражения. И именно таким образом определяется NULL.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612975/178988

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Понятия "null pointer value" и "null pointer constant" - приниципльно разные вещи, которые в одинаковой мере присутствуют и в С и в С++. Смысл каждого из них совершенно одинаков смысл и в С и в С++. Утверждение, что null pointer value в С++ соответствует null pointer constant в C - не верно.

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, в языке С `NULL` - это либо `(void *) 0`, либо целочисленный константный `0` (просто `0`, `0L`, `0LL` и т.п.) Так что никакого заранее заданного конкретного размера у результата выражения `NULL` в языке С нет.

Во-вторых, вывод вашего кода обсуждать бессмысленно про причине попыток печатать результат `sizeof` через `%d`. Результат `sizeof` имеет тип `size_t`, который в общем случае не совместим со спецификатором формата `%d`.

Однако в любом случае не было бы ничего необычного, если бы на вашей платформе `NULL` был бы объявлен как `(void *) 0` и размер результата такого выражения равнялся бы 8 байтам. Поэтому не совсем понятно, что вызвало ваш вопрос.

Comment: А что плохого в том чтобы выводить через %d?

Comment: @MaximPro выведенное значение может [не соответствовать действительности](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/DHPlC2vfCBZIdH0A) потому что.

Comment: @alexolut да, я понимаю, но для малых чисел то какая разница?

Comment: @MaximPro разница будет при ином порядке байт в частности.

Comment: @alexolut например?

Comment: @MaximPro например на big-endian машине

Comment: @alexolut, откровенно говоря, на *очень странной машине*. Она должна быть 64-bit (или более), а аргументы должны передаваться через стек. Если интересно, можете почитать [Calling convention)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) в вике

Comment: @MaximPro, с другой стороны, gcc просто пишет warning при таком использовании printf, что раздражает. Для "переносимости" я просто пишу `(int)sizeof(...)`

Comment: @MaximPro: Разница огромна. При несовпадении формата поведение не определено, независимо от того, малые числа или не малые. На практике передача переменных аргументов - это фактически бинарная упаковка и распаковка данных, где ошибка в один байт полностью уничтожает функциональность кода.

Comment: @avp: Для переносимости уже давно есть `%zu` для печати значений типа `size_t`.

Comment: Я [знаю](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), только обычно не помню, что именно когда надо писать.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612975/178988

Answer (score 2):

По крайней мере, в Visual C++

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(NULL));
```

то же самое, что

```
printf("%d\n",sizeof(void*));
```

Соответственно, выводимое значение зависит от того, какой код компилируется и чем :)

Так, Visual C++ даст 4 при компиляции 32-разрядного приложения, и 8 - при компиляции 64-разрядного. Еще раз - *приложения*, а не *операционной системы*.

**Update**
Из Windows Kits -

```
#ifndef NULL
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define NULL 0
    #else
        #define NULL ((void *)0)
    #endif
#endif
```

Так что в режиме C++ в обоих вариантах Visual C++ выдаст 4. Но, поскольку тэг был "[c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)", то все верно...

Примерно так же описан `NULL` и в Open Watcom.

Цитирую из "С Справочник. Полное описание языка":

*Константа нулевого указателя — это целочисленная константа со значением `0`, или константное целочисленное значение `0`, приведенное к типу указателя на `void`. Макрос `NULL` определяется в заголовочных файлах `stdlib.h`, `stdio.h` и др.*

**Update 2**
Из стандарта -
*The macro NULL is defined in  (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.17.*

*The macros are `NULL` which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51867/discussion-on-answer-by-harry-sizeofnull-8).