# Обязательно ли NULL в Си является указателем?

Tags: c, null, language-lawyer

Вопрос на основе обсуждения [ответа про `sizeof NULL`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612905/178988).

Вот куски стандарта:

> **An integer constant expression with the value 0**, ***or*** such an expression cast to type `void *`, **is called a null pointer constant**
>
> **NULL** which **expands to an implementation-deﬁned null pointer constant**

Кажется, что не запрещено вместо `#define NULL ((void*)0)` сделать просто `#define NULL 0`, как это сделано в плюсах. Тогда получается, что `sizeof NULL` равен либо `sizeof (void*)`, либо `sizeof (int)` (в варианте `sizeof 0`).

Однако, [@Vlad from Moscow](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183394/vlad-from-moscow) [утверждает](//ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612766/sizeofnull-8/612905?noredirect=1#comment843842_612905), что NULL в Си обязан быть указателем.

> NULL в С определен как указатель.
>
> Ключевое значение в приведенной цитате имеют слова "cast to type void *".
>
> Здесь `или` имеет отношение не к приведению типов, а к виду выражения. И именно таким образом определяется NULL.

Так допустимо ли для Си (без плюсов) иметь?

```
#define NULL 0
```

И если допустимо, то почему в компиляторах используется

```
#ifndef NULL
    #ifdef __cplusplus
        #define NULL 0
    #else
        #define NULL ((void *)0)
    #endif
#endif
```

вместо более простого варианта с нулём для обоих языков?
Ведь в си даже перегрузки функций не было, чтобы можно было что-то сломать.

Comment: возможно это прояснит http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502811/sizeof-int-sizeof-void

Comment: Может поможет получить ответы. В [этом вопросе на SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894013/is-null-always-zero-in-c) есть ссылка на ресурс [comp.lang.c Frequently Asked Questions](http://c-faq.com/) и в частности на [список null pointer вопросов](http://c-faq.com/null/) -> [ответ на 5.16](http://c-faq.com/null/confusion4.html). Судя по всему в Си NULL всегда указатель.

Comment: Не знаю, как именно это сделано, но, например, gcc понимает, что список аргументов `execl` должен завершаться нулевым (константа(!)) указателем (не важно `(void *)0` или хоть `(float *)0`). Кстати, понимает, даже если unistd.h не включать. Поэтому использовать всюду просто 0 не получится.

Comment: там все просто - достаточно посмотреть описания функции полностью `extern int execle (const char *__path, const char *__arg, ...)
     __THROW __nonnull ((1, 2));` - то есть, просто есть указания компилятору ещё на этапе разбора проверить. Но это расширение компилятора gcc. почему подобное не запилить в стандарт - не знаю.

Comment: @AlexKrass, там предлагают внутренности нуля обнулить, а не константу изменить.

Comment: @KoVadim только вот `__nonnull((1, 2))` относятся к первому и второму аргументам списка вызова, а не к последнему (его компайлер называет `sentinel` и ругается `warning: missing sentinel in function call [-Wformat=]`). Причем, это где-то прописано для `execl` (и очевидно, кучи др. функций), потому что, когда я убираю unistd.h и вручную прописываю одинаковые декларации execl и execf, то ругань **только на execl**

Comment: Ха, по идее `(void *)0 != 0`. Думаю легко понять почему.

Comment: @0andriy, вообще-то нет, не понятно.

Comment: @avp, тот самый `-Wformat`, который про формат printf'а говорит?

Comment: @Qwertiy, пока не знаю. Надо бы разобраться, понять как описать свой прототип, чтобы компайлер предупреждал об отсутствии sentinel

Comment: ОК, нашел. В https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#Common-Function-Attributes ищем `sentinel` и читаем -- `The attribute is automatically set with a position of 0 for the built-in functions execl and execlp. The built-in function execle has the attribute set with a position of 1.`, а также обращаем внимание на -- `The warnings for missing or incorrect sentinels are enabled with -Wformat.` (в принципе все гуглится по `gcc -Wformat=`, потом берем gcc online documentation и там в keyword index ищем ^F format)

Comment: @Qwertiy нет гарантии соответствия размерности типов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а в плюсах тоже по очевидным причинам нельзя использовать `(void *)0`.

Comment: @0andriy, в практике программирования на С  `(void *)0 != 0 is false` -- (легко проверить одним `printf()`), а вот с "теоретической" т.з. (до приведения типов при трансляции выражения) -- true. Однако, это true на практике не увидеть (похоже пора подбросить любителям философии новую категорию (или как у них там такие вещи зовутся?) -- *виртуальная истина*)

Comment: @avp *истина в железе* уж ;) Но да, на практике такое предотвращается компилятором.

Comment: @avp, @0andriy, не очень понял ваши комментарии про теоретическую точку зрения. Стандарт языка C гарантирует, что `(void *)0 != 0 is false`.

Comment: @wololo, 0 это int (или unsigned int в зависимости от компилятора) и в большинстве случаев даже на 64-bit машине занимает 4 байта. `void *` -- указатель и на той же 64-bit машине занимает 8 байт. Теоретически 4 байта нулей не равны 8 байтам нулей (размер у них разный)

Comment: @avp, `char a = 1`, `double b = 1.0`. `a` и `b` скорее всего  имеют разный размер и разные битовые паттерны, а значит, последовательность битов, представляющих переменную `a` не равна последовательности битов, представляющей переменную `b`. Однако, это не отменяет того факта, что результат выражения `a != b` — это `0`.

Comment: @wololo, понял, вы говорите о правилах в языке Си. Тут, конечно, (из-за неявных преобразований типов) все так. Мы с  @ 0andriy скорее говорили тут об абстактном железе

Comment: @avp, а теперь я понял вас :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Просмотрев внимательно стандарт C, я думаю, что вы правы. null pointer constant - это либо целочисленное константное выражение со значением 0, либо такое выражение, приведенное к типу `void *`.

Поэтому определение макроса `NULL` может быть в принципе различным, зависящим от реализации компилятора. То есть нигде в стандарте C я не нашел, что макрос NULL обязан быть определен как

```
( void *)0
```

Я заглянул в документ Rationale for International Standard— Programming Languages— C и там нашел следующее (7.17    Common definitions )

> 25 NULL can be defined as any null pointer constant.  Thus existing
>   code can retain definitions of NULL as 0 or 0L, but an implementation
>   may also choose to define it as (void*)0.  **This latter form of
>   definition is convenient on architectures where sizeof(void*) does not
>   equal the size of any integer type.**

Так как **null pointer constant** преобразуется в выражениях в **null pointer**, а размер `null pointer` может быть не равен размеру ни одному целочисленному типу, то удобнее определять `null pointer constant` как

```
( void * )0
```

то есть сразу же приводить ее к типу указателя.

В C++ от такого определения отказались, так как в отличии от C в C++ в связи с обеспечением безопасности типов нужно явное приведение указателя на `void` к типу указателя на конкретный объект. То есть если `null pointer constant` `NULL` будет определена в C++ как

```
( void *)0
```

то вам придется делать явное приведение указателей, как, например,

```
int *p = ( int * )( void *)0;
```

что, естественно, очень обременительно.

Поэтому в C++ Отказались объявлять `NULL` в виде целочисленной константы, приведенной к типу `void *`.

Comment: `0L` - неожиданный вариант... Хотя и логичный, пожалуй. А требования на совпадение размера с размером указателя нет? Т. е. это просто заметка, которая ни к чему не обязывает?

Comment: В современных плюсах `NULL` и вовсе не рекомендуется использовать. Появился `nullptr`.