# Что это значит `str[i]!=(char)NULL`?

Tags: c++

Что это значит `str[i]!=(char)NULL`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86296/discussion-on-question-by-zhoskiy--stricharnull).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Этот код "ничего" не значит, так как этот код в общем случае некорректен. Что скрывается за макро `NULL` в языке C++ - определяется реализацией. Макро `NULL` в современном C++ может быть определено как `nullptr`, а значение `nullptr` не может быть преобразовано к типу `char`.

Макро `NULL` предназначено для использования в указательных контекстах. Использование `NULL` в целочисленных контекстах - практически всегда ошибка, признак некомпетентного и низкокачественного кода. С появлением в языке С++ `nullptr` и с разрешением определять `NULL` именно как `nullptr` использование `NULL` в целочисленных контекстах в языке С++ фактически *запрещено*.

Даже до С++11 и `nullptr` многие компиляторы выдавали диагностические сообщения на использование `NULL` в целочисленных контекстах.

P.S. При этом стоит иметь в виду, что даже в языке С не гарантируется, что приведение `NULL` к целочисленному типу дает целочисленное значение `0`.

Comment: _"An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type void *, is called a null pointer constant

    NULL which expands to an implementation-deﬁned null pointer constant"_ - так что NULL обязан привестись именно к нулю (ну, если сможет, по крайней мере). Обсуждалось тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/612975/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: Я говорю именно о варианте `(void *) 0`. Результат обратного преобразования `(int)(void *) 0` в языке С является implementation-defined и **не обязан** давать целочисленный `0`. По вашей ссылке я не увидел ничего по теме `(int) NULL`.

Comment: Почуму не обязан? Вроде как раз все возможные значения нулевых указателей (даже если указатели различны) обязаны привестить к целочисленному нулю при таком приведении?

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: На основании чего вы делаете такой вывод? Спецификация языка C ничего подобного нигде не гарантирует. Да и зачем? `NULL` не предназначен для таких использований. Более того, было бы совершенно естественным ожидать, что на платформе, где null-указатели физически представляются как, скажем, `0xFFFFFFFF`, результат  `(int)(void *) 0` даст именно `0xFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: Не могу найти, но где-то уже обсуждалось. [Позвал](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47792438#47792438) VladD :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Я помню обсуждение, но не могу сходу найти. Просмотрел стандарт, не нашёл там гарантии, что каст `nullptr` к `int` даст 0, только гарантии, что `nullptr == (void*)0` http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#4

Comment: @VladD: `nullptr`? `nullptr` в принципе не может быть преобразован к целочисленному типу, ни явно, ни неявно, никак. Никакой "каст" этого не делает. Поэтому даже темы такой не существует, не говоря уже о каких-то "гарантиях".

Comment: @AnT: Отсутствие неявного преобразования очевидно (это была цель введения `nullptr`), а вот отсутствие явного для меня новость.

Comment: @AnT: Но исходя из моей ссылки `reinterpret_cast` по крайней мере обязан компилироваться

Comment: @reinterpret_cast: Да, вы правы. Действительно, `reinterpret_cast` применим к `nullptr`, однако его семантика совпадает с `reinterpret_cast<...>((void *) 0)`. То есть опять же - ожидаемым результатом будет не `0`, а именно физическое представление null-указателя на данной платформе. На платформах, где null-указатель физически представляется как `0xBAADF00D`, `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(nullptr)` будет давать именно `0xBAADF00D`.

Comment: @VladD,   по крайней мере `gcc/g++` версии 7.3.0 без всяких слов приводят и `NULL` и `nullptr` к `int`-у через  приведение к `(size_t)`

Comment: @avp: Так к `size_t` или к `int`? Как уже сказано выше, `reinterpret_cast` допустим, но только к целым типам достаточного размера. И, еще раз, никакого `0` в результате никто не обещает.

Comment: @AnT, `int x = (size_t)nullptr;
  cout << "x=" << x << '\n';` результат: `avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out
x=0
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$`

Comment: @avp: Я не совсем понимаю, что именно вы пытаетесь продемонстрировать. Можно ли явно привести `nullptr` к `size_t`? Да, через `reinterpret_cast`, если размера `size_t` достаточно. Будет ли получаться `0`? Зависит от платформы, не гарантированно. `int` же здесь вообще ни к чему никакого отношения не имеет. Это уже сто раз было сказано. В чем ценность примера?

Comment: @AnT, не вы ли 19 часов назад написали в комментарии -- *`nullptr? nullptr в принципе не может быть преобразован к целочисленному типу, ни явно, ни неявно, никак. Никакой "каст" этого не делает. Поэтому даже темы такой не существует, не говоря уже о каких-то "гарантиях".`*?  Или int не целочисленный тип?

Comment: @avp: Во-первых, я уже поправился в отношении этого огульного утверждения 12 часов назад: "Да, вы правы. Действительно, `reinterpret_cast` применим к `nullptr`..." Во-вторых, никакого преобразования к `int` в вашем примере нет. Есть преобразование к `size_t`. А что вы там потом с этим `size_t` делаете - к рассматриваемому вопросу не относится вообще никак. Напоминаю, что в исходном вопросе делается попытка преобразования `nullptr` к `char`.

Comment: @AnT, ну извините, не внимательно прочел все комментарии. Вы бы лучше объяснили все же автору вопроса, какую цепочку кастов и почему надо делать для получения в char младшего байта (CHAR_BIT младших бит) указателя

Comment: @avp: Я на 99.9% уверен, что вопрос не имеет никакого даже отдаленного отношения к "младшим битам указателя". Несложно догадаться, что код, который мы видим в вопросе: это попытка использовать `NULL` в качестве значения нулевого терминатора `\0` в строке. Эта дубовая манера периодически встречается в низкокачественном/студенческом коде. Автору вопроса надо объяснить, что применять `NULL` в этой роли ни в коем случае нельзя. Мне кажется, я это уже сделал.

Comment: @AnT, будем надеяться, что автор дочитает до этого места и сообразит, что надо писать просто `str[i] != 0`. / Может заодно задумается о внутреннем представлении переменных в компе, заинтересуется, почитает и будет лучше понимать, как программировать кусочки кремния